# Sub Queries in an ORDER BY clause MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, e-commerce

Im writing a module for an e-commerce platform that modifies the ORDER BY clause of an MySQL query.

I only have access to anything after the ORDER BY statment.

Im wanting to execute ORDER BY statements on calculated columns as such.

```
" ORDER BY (SELECT (shop_product.price - shop_product.sale_price) as pSavings) ASC "
```

Although i have no idea how i would go about this or if its even possible as i dont have access to the SELECT statement to generate the calculated columns?

Comment: There is no need to make `as` statment in `ORDER BY` clause. remove the select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean this (then it is possible):

```
ORDER BY (shop_product.price - shop_product.sale_price) ASC
```

Comment: beware thought that this will result in a full table scan

Comment: Not entirely true if there is WHERE condition. Since database would filter out unnecessary rows first before sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try with this.

```
SELECT (shop_product.price - shop_product.sale_price) as pSavings ORDER BY pSavings ASC;
```